# OAuth2 (Keycloak): client_credentials grant type additional claims

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have a scenario wherein there are multiple apps/service that need to access my Resource:

These are the three external services: service1, service2, service3.

Now I am using the client_credentials grant type for this since this is machine to machine and no user is involved.

What I did is to create 1 client for each service in Keycloak. It works fine, however I need to add some more details in the token, in particular, a human readable name for each client as the client id is named using the [recommended naming](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/).

I know how to map user claims to the token, but is it possible to have something similar for my scenario wherein there are no users and I only have the clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, go to the Realm of your app, then:

- Go to Clients;
- Select your client;
- Select Mappers;
- click on the button `[Create]`;
- select `Hardcoded Claim` as `Mapper Type`;
- fill up the details of the claim

Click `[Save]`.

---

**Update answer with more detail**

> I know how to map user claims to the token, but is it possible to have
> something similar for my scenario wherein there are no users and I
> only have the clients?

Yes, you need to create 'Hardcoded Claim Mapper.

For that:

- Select the `realm` of your app
- Go to `clients`
- Select the appropriate `client` for your use-case

**(For the OLD Keycloak UI)**

- Go to `Mappers`
- Click `Create`
- In `Mapper type` select `Hardcoded claim`
- Fill up the details of the claim, accordingly.
- Click on `Save`

**(For the NEW Keycloak UI)**

- Go to the tab `Client Scopes`
- Click on the client scope `<the client ID of your client>-dedicated` (*e.g.,* test-dedicated in the picture below)

[image]

- Click on `Configure a new mapper` (or `Add Mapper` >  `By configuration` if you have already created mappers before for this client)

[image]

- Select `Hardcoded claim`
- Fill up the details of the claim, accordingly.
- Click on `Save`

The client will be the client that you are using to authenticate against.

Comment: is there a dynamic way for this? something like providing a header eg 'claims' when requesting the client_credentials grant Token, and then keycloak adding these to the token payload?

Comment: @eja Yep, have a look a this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71247870/correct-way-to-customize-keycloak-access-token-with-scenario-where-were-using-a/71249185#71249185