# Correct way to customize keycloak access token with scenario where we're using azure ad as authentication provider[Keycloak]

Tags: keycloak, access-token, roles

We are using azure ad as an idp for authentication, We want to add additional attributes like `roles` etc. to the `access token`. These additional attributes are coming from existing application.

What is the correct way to get these attributes from existing system and add to the access token?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own custom claim mapper as presented in [here](https://medium.com/@pavithbuddhima/how-to-add-custom-claims-to-jwt-tokens-from-an-external-source-in-keycloak-52bd1ff596d3). Which reads the custom claims from the application and adds them to the token.

Alternatively, you can also use [script mappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518298/how-to-create-a-script-mapper-in-keycloak). Finally, you can also have a look at UMA flow and use the feature of [pushing claims](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_pushing_claims).